# Can't save my C file in VS code due to clang error

Tags: clang

It is showing this error
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'progrm'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '6.c'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '6'
clang: error: no input files

I was trying to save my program in Vs code but it is showing some error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.